# transposing a single column into multiple rows with a marker

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have a data in an excel sheet (also in text file and csv) looks like this:

```
;;
A
1
2
3

;;
B
1
2

;;
C
1
2
3
4
5
```

Each group has a marker ";;" , and there is a space after each group. The length vary.
I would like to transpose into multiple rows like this:

```
A 1 2 3
B 1 2
C 1 2 3 4 5
```

I couldn't find a formula or a macro for this task.

Thanks

Comment: "I couldn't find a formula or a macro for this task." Did you at least try and have a go? If so, where did you get stuck? If not, why not? SU isn't a VBA macro-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this, just `INDEX/MATCH` and a bit of imagination.

[image]

The data is in column A, starting at cell A1. Columns B-F calculate various items, explained below, whilst the output starts at cell H1.

The data is grouped into "blocks" and column B simply identifies the block number to which a particular data item belongs - the block number is incremented whenever the ;; marker is found. Column C shows the relative position within each block of a data item, with 0  indicating that the corresponding cell in column A is excluded from the output.

Cells D1 and E1 are simply the maximum values found in columns B and C and respectively indicate the number of blocks and the maximum number of items within any block. The output will, therefore, fit with a rectangular array of cells containing D1 rows and E1 columns.

If every block contained the same number and therefore maximum number of items (say 6 as in the example shown) then we could simply number the items as 1-6 in the first block, 7-12 in the second, 13-18 in the third, etc and map items 1-6 as the first row of put, 7-12 as the second, 13-18 as the third, etc.

Effectively, this approach is used, except that any unused item numbers are ignored. Column F provides the item number and, for example, because block 1 only contains 4 items the values 5 and 6 do not appear in column F and the first item in block 2 (cell A8) is given an item number of 7 (cell F8).

The snippet `$E$1*(ROW(H1)-1)+COLUMN(H1)-7` in cell H1 when copied to adjacent cells generates the (theoretical) item number appropriate to the output row and column. (Cell H1 is in row 1 and column 1 of the output) The `MATCH`function in H1 tests to see whether the item number is found in column F. If it is found, the `INDEX` part delivers the appropriate value from column A. Otherwise, if the item number is not matched in column F, the #N/A that would result is caught by the `IFERROR` function and replaced with a null string.

Dependent on the nature of the input data, refinements of this approach are possible, for example to avoid the repeated use of `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions across all the potential output cells, but the approach set out above provides a starting  point.