# Concatenate sequential column cells into row cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to transpose the columns of data in this format:

[Input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQdmg.png)

| A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 | F1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | W | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
| B | X | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| C | Y | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| D | Z | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |

Into this desired result:

[Output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfcp7.png)

| A1 | B1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | W1 |
| A | W2 |
| A | W3 |
| B | X1 |
| B | X2 |
| C | Y1 |
| C | Y2 |
| C | Y3 |
| C | Y4 |
| D | Z1 |
| D | Z2 |
| D | Z3 |

However, the autofill won't find a pattern.

ex.

- $B1,$C1
- $B1,$C2
- $B1,$C3
- $B1,$C4
- **$B2,$C1**

vs.

- $B1,$C1
- $B1,$C2
- $B1,$C3
- $B1,$C4
- **$B5,$C5**

I don't know how to tell it to "restart" the row number again, or "+1 every *x* rows".

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a reverse of [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1694925/transposing-a-single-column-into-multiple-rows-with-a-marker/1694959#1694959) from a day or so back. The older problem sought to take a column of data and organise it into variable length rows. The current problem seeks to change data organised in variable length rows to a column arrangement.

I have used a similar sort of approach to that involved in dealing with the earlier problem. This approach implictly counts the items along the variable part of the rows (3rd column onwards). So, for the example input shown in the OP,
this count is 1,2,3 for the first row, 4,5 for second row, 6,7,8,9 for third row and 10,11,12 for the fourth row. The first counted value for each row is used explicitly in the solution.

[image: Screenshot of solution used]

The small table (range `A6:C11`) identifies the size of the variable part of each input row in column *Length*. Column *First* identifies the first count value for each row of input. The total value (cell `B11`) determines how many output items (rows) are required. Note that cell `C7` contains the static value 1.

The helper table (range `E6:G18`) determines for each *Item* of output, the number of the *Row* and *Column* of the input that is used to create the output (where the numbering of the input *Column*s counts the variable length part of each input row, so 1 for the third input column, 2 for the fourth, etc). Column *First* is used to calculate the *Row* and *Column* values.